# How to set LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile libftdi for arm. When I run Cmake I get:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
```

I understand that LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR ought to be set in FindUSB1.cmake found in the libftdi root directory. However, I have no clue on how to make FindUSB1.cmake find libusb that I have compiled and put into /opt/lib. This is the default file:

```
# - Try to find the freetype library
# Once done this defines
#
#  LIBUSB_FOUND - system has libusb
#  LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR - the libusb include directory
#  LIBUSB_LIBRARIES - Link these to use libusb

# Copyright (c) 2006, 2008  Laurent Montel, <montel@kde.org>
#
# Redistribution and use is allowed according to the terms of the BSD license.
# For details see the accompanying COPYING-CMAKE-SCRIPTS file.


if (LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR AND LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)

  # in cache already
  set(LIBUSB_FOUND TRUE)

else (LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR AND LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)
  IF (NOT WIN32)
    # use pkg-config to get the directories and then use these values
    # in the FIND_PATH() and FIND_LIBRARY() calls

    find_package(PkgConfig)
    pkg_check_modules(PC_LIBUSB libusb-1.0)
  ENDIF(NOT WIN32)

  FIND_PATH(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR libusb.h
    PATHS ${PC_LIBUSB_INCLUDEDIR} ${PC_LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  FIND_LIBRARY(LIBUSB_LIBRARIES NAMES usb-1.0
    PATHS ${PC_LIBUSB_LIBDIR} ${PC_LIBUSB_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
  FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(LIBUSB DEFAULT_MSG LIBUSB_LIBRARIES LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR)

  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)

endif (LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR AND LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)
```

In /opt/lib there is a directory pkconfig. In this directory there is a libusb-1.0.pc file that I guess might have something to do with the problem. So how should I get Cmake to find /opt/lib/libsub-1.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default find script is not very powerful. If the library is not located in [one of the default directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_library) searched by `find_library`, you have to rely on [`pkg-config`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) to tell you where the library is located.

In the (not so unlikely) event that the library is not registered with `pkg-config` either, you have no choice but setting the `PC_LIBUSB_LIBDIR` and `PC_LIBUSB_INCLUDEDIR` variables manually before calling the find script. This can be done either from the command line (using the [`-D` parameter](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt:-Dvar:typevalue)) or from within the enclosing CMake script (using [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:set)).

If you are at liberty to make changes to the find script, consider adding additional `HINTS` to the find calls to make them more flexible. For instance, using an environment variable as a hint is a quite popular mechanism that also works well for non-Unix platforms.

```
FIND_PATH(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR libusb.h
    HINTS $ENV{LIBUSB_ROOT}
    PATHS ${PC_LIBUSB_INCLUDEDIR} ${PC_LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include)

FIND_LIBRARY(LIBUSB_LIBRARIES NAMES usb-1.0
    HINTS $ENV{LIBUSB_ROOT}
    PATHS ${PC_LIBUSB_LIBDIR} ${PC_LIBUSB_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
```

Since CMake version 3.12, CMake will automatically take the [`<PackageName>_ROOT` variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html#variable:%3CPackageName%3E_ROOT) into account as hints for calls to `find_package` calls, and all nested `find_*` calls made from within a find script that was triggered by a call to `find_package`. So in those cases, you won't have to specify them manually as hints anymore. Note that for this to work, your [`cmake_minimum_required`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) version needs to be set to 3.12 or higher.