# CMake add_subdirectory with find_package?

Tags: c, cmake

I have the following structure of projects/source:

```
MyProject
|-MyProject
| |-src
| | |-project.c
| |
| |-CMakeLists.txt
|
|-MyLibrary
  |-include
  | |-hello.h
  |
  |-src
  | |-hello.c
  |
  |-CMakeLists.txt
```

`MyProject/src/project.c` includes `MyLibrary/include/hello.h`, which in turn includes `libusb.h` from the system (found using CMake).

And I am adding the libusb dependency in `MyLibrary/CMakeLists.txt` using the following code:

```
# Find libusb
find_package(LibUsb REQUIRED)

# Include libusb
include_directories(${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Add dependencies
target_link_libraries(owi535 ${LIBUSB_LIBRARY})
```

However when compiling `MyProject` (which includes `MyLibrary` using `add_subdirectory` and `target_link_libraries`), I get an error stating `libusb.h` cannot be found.

I can compile `MyLibrary` on it's own, however compiling `MyProject` requires `libusb.h` to be in it's include path, which it is not.

Is there a way to make it so that by adding `MyLibrary` as a dependency, `MyProject` pulls `libusb.h` through it? This would mean that I don't need to repeat the `find_package` code for every project that includes `MyLibrary`.

---

The other issue I am having is similar; I am getting an error stating that there are `Undefined symbols` when calling libusb functions in `MyLibrary` when I compile `MyProject`, however when compiling `MyLibrary` on it's own, there are no errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libusb_close", referenced from:
      _my_close_method in libMyLibrary.a(hello.c.o)
  "_libusb_exit", referenced from:
      _my_exit_method in libMyLibrary.a(hello.c.o)
  "_libusb_init", referenced from:
      _my_init_method in libMyLibrary.a(hello.c.o)
  "_libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid", referenced from:
      _my_open_method in libMyLibrary.a(hello.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html):

> `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` items will populate the [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) property of <target>.
>
> Targets may populate this property [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`] to publish the include directories required to compile against the headers for the target. Consuming targets can add entries to their own `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property such as `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>` to use the include directories specified in the interface of foo.

So, you need to use this in `MyLibrary/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_include_directories(MyLibrary PUBLIC ${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with linking the actual library. Getting an `Undefined symbols` pertaining to libusb when compiling `MyProject` but `MyLibrary` compiles fine on it's own. Is there a similar fix to this?

Comment: This is a separate issue. You can reaccept this answer and open a new question with your new issue.

Comment: But to answer your question, it looks like you aren't actually linking the libusb library into MyLibrary correctly. It won't error out when compiling MyLibrary directly since it appears you are using static linking.

Comment: I think @jackwilsdon second problem looks like a typo. Could it be `LIBUSB_LIBRARIES` instead of `LIBUSB_LIBRARY`? E.g. if I look at [How to set LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814266/how-to-set-libusb-include-dir)